# how to hide password in selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am working with our website automation testing script.
We have some part-time staff members we like ask them to run this script to monitoring all our web service.

There is an secure problem before I give this to them to run, because they can see the user name and password inside of code. VS `C#` + SpecFlow and Selenium.

How can I hide them? Or, how can I ask them to input their own username + password?

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "userNameInput")]
private IWebElement loginUsername;

public void UserName()
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("userNameInput")));
    loginUsername.Click();
    loginUsername.SendKeys("admin");
}

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "passwordInput")]
private IWebElement loginPassword;

public void Password()
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("passwordInput")));
    loginPassword.Click();
    loginPassword.SendKeys("SAd@12340");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: hope that's not a real password...

Comment: nope, it just randomly created example, thanks

Comment: https://developers.perfectomobile.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21430626

Answer (score 0):

Having tried various methods this is the one I went with in the end. Add this method into a GeneralStepDefinition file with TestRunContext passed into the constructor of that class using SpecFlow's Dependency Injection.  Then save that password into an AppSettings static property (not ideal but given SpecFlow discourages OOP IMHO, the least worst solution). You will also need a key value json pairing for e.g. "TestUserPassword": "password123" inside an appsettings.json file at the top level of your project.

```
[BeforeScenario]
    public void SetupPassword()
    {
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(_testRunContext.TestDirectory, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
        AppSettings.TestUserPassword = config.GetValue<string>("TestUserPassword");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In C# you can save sensitive information in **app.config** file, like this:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ShopBaseUrl" value="http://automationpractice.com/index.php" />
  </appSettings>
```

And then take this information, using this code:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShopBaseUrl"]);
```

Which will return to you a value from **app.config**, which has key: **ShopBaseUrl**

Comment: but the people who use my automation script in the VisualStudio also have access to App.Config, right? they still can see my password from the code.

Comment: If they know, where to search, then they can find it. If no, then they will not find it. Then other solution would be storing passwords on external services, like KeyWault, and take then at the run time.